# How is this causing an infinite loop?

Tags: java, list, loops

I have found this method to be the source of my problems for my program. It involves a linked list called 'theBoard' with chesspiece objects in it. When stepping through my debugger, my debugger ends when it hits this checking method. Anyone know what's the problem with it?

EDIT: This method checks if one chesspiece in the linked list can attack another chesspiece in the linked list. It takes theBoard (the linked list object created in another class where pieces were added) as a parameter.

the method '.isAttacking' checks if one piece can attack the other (method in each piece class, each piece class extending an abstract "chessPiece" class).

Am I doing something wrong? I'm using Intellij debugger and going line by line. Once I hit this method call, the debugger seems to stop.

```
public void checkAttacking (chessBoard theBoard) throws FileNotFoundException {

    boolean foundPieces = false;
    Link current = theBoard.head;

    while (current != null) {

        Link current2 = theBoard.head;
        while (current2 != null) {

            if (current != current2) {

                if ((current.piece.isAttacking(current2.piece)) && foundPieces == false) {

                   System.out.println(current.piece.pieceType + " " + current.piece.col +
                    " " + current.piece.row + " " + current2.piece.pieceType +
                    " " + current2.piece.col + " " + current2.piece.row);
                    foundPieces = true;
                }
            }
            current2 = current2.next;
        }
        current = current.next;
    }
    if (foundPieces == false) {
        System.out.print("-");
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Would you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41914995/edit) to clarify?  What is the infinite loop you are experiencing?  What do you mean by "my debugger ends"?  Which is the "checking method" you are referring to?  Thanks!

Comment: You have two loops.

Comment: Edited it for clarification

Comment: Have you tried to step into that method?

Comment: How would I step into that method from the debugger if I started the debugger in another class? (look at my name if this question seems basic :( )

Comment: Because if this method is looping the code is useless

Comment: My suggestion is to search before asking. A lot of questions have already been answered. Do a search intellij debugger step into then repost

Comment: But after finding if one link's object's row/col value equals another objec'ts row/col value, it prints each piece and their row/col and ends the method by returning

Comment: Okay, I figured out how to move into that method. It simply keeps repeating in the loop. Shouldn't it move onto the next object in the link?

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong with the code that you've showed us, but what about the code that you haven't showed us?  What happens in `isAttacking()`?  How do you know that the problem isn't there?  And what builds `theBoard`?  How do you know that the loop is not in the data structure?

Comment: @jameslarge Am I accessing the head correctly and moving onto the next link in the list correctly? I think that might be my issue

Comment: @NoviceProgrammer123 well, that surely is not java.util.LinkedList, it doesn't have such fields available. And if it's your custom list - you'll need to add that code to the question for us to be able to judge that.

Comment: Your loops will terminate when they reach a `null`, but how do I know that there _is_ a `null`?  What if the `.next` of the last item in the list points back to some other item in the list? That construction is called a _circular list_.  Sometimes it's a useful thing to create on purpose.  But maybe you created one by accident.  If you call `checkAttacking()` on a circular list, it will never return. Until you show us the code that created the list, we have no way to know.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList list=new LinkedList<>();
        int i=0;
        while(list!=null){
            System.out.println("Welcome");
            i++;
            if(i>100)
                System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my sample of the code. The result is 100x "Welcome" text.
I think that you have the same problem.

```
 while (current != null)
```

In your loop you check if the reference object "current" of type LinkedList is null or not. 
If you have created object in other class(you said that you did it) your contidtion is every time true. So you have infinite loop.

If you want to check every object in current list, I propose to use Iterator and hasNext(),next() method or for-each loop.
See you.